# acumatica and notification templates and business events and sending to multiple contact emails at once

Tags: acumatica

We have a requirement to be able to send an email to all contacts within a customer/business account via a notification template/business events.

We are planning to use business events to trigger when there is a change of some sort to the customer record. At that moment, we want to have a notification template sent out to all of the contacts on that customer record.

We don't see a way iterate through the contacts to get the email addresses and populate into the to/cc fields.

My thought was that if we can create a field that has a comma separated list of contact emails, we could just populate the to field with this concatenated list, but not sure if that will work.

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After further testing, it does appear that we can just populate a comma separated list of email addresses that are pulled from another field on the data object we are working with on the notification template. So we will just iterate through the contacts to build a comma separated list of all of the email addresses and store that with the opportunity object so that we can populate the "to" fields on the notification template.